# How to correctly set return type of NGXS selectors

Tags: angular, ngxs

When using selectors with parameters in NGXS, you return a create selector function, but this way I need to set the return type of the `single` selector to `any` and it actually is `AccountDetails`.

```
@Selector([AccountsDbState])
public static single(id: string): any {
    return createSelector([AccountsDbState], (state: RootStateModel) => {
        return state.database.accounts.items.find(x => x.id === id);
    });
}
```

If try to type it as `AccountDetails` I get the following error from intellisense:

> Type '(state: RootStateModel) => AccountDetails' is missing the following properties from type 'AccountDetails': id, code, openingBalance, openingDate, and 3 more.ts(2740)

Is there any way to correctly type this kind of selectors?

--- UPDATE ---

Full selector file contents:

```
import { createSelector, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';
import { AccountDetails } from '@models/accounts';
import { RootStateModel } from '@state/root-state';
import { AccountsDbState } from './accounts.state';
import { DatabaseStoreStateModel } from 'ngx-rbk-utils';

export class AccountsDbSelectors {
    @Selector([AccountsDbState])
    public static all(state: DatabaseStoreStateModel<AccountDetails>): AccountDetails[] {
        return state.items;
    }

    @Selector([AccountsDbState])
    public static single(id: string): any {
        return createSelector([AccountsDbState], (state: RootStateModel) => {
            return state.database.accounts.items.find(x => x.id === id);
        });
    }
}
```

The examples in the [NGXS Selector documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select) don't set return types in any function :(

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you're doing without more code, but at first glance you may need to use a generic or a union type, something other than the any type. Could you share more code? I understand the error, but I don't know where/how you're getting that error from the selector code you're showing.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport Thanks, I updated the question with the whole `.ts` file

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you need the `@Selector()` decorator and the `createSelector()` function at the same time. I'm not sure what that would do. I would remove the decorator. I know the comments are not a great place for code, but here is one of mine: `  public static get(name: string) {
    return createSelector([SETTINGS_STATE_TOKEN], (settings: SettingsStateModel) => settings[name]);
  }` and TS infers the correct type. Note: I do not have this `get()` function decorated.